# Are Gadfly plots currently composable?

Tags: ggplot2, julia, gadfly

Is there currently a way to add plot elements together in Gadfly.jl?

For example, in R if I have another function that returns a ggplot and I want to add a title to it, I'd do the following:

```
p <- makeMyPlot()
p + ggtitle("Now it has a title")
```

Is there currently a Gadfly equivalent? If not, is this on Gadfly's roadmap?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`add_plot_element()`](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/Gadfly.jl#L166-L188), which can add stuff to an existing layer:

```
xs = [0:0.1:pi]
l = layer(x=xs, y=sin(xs))
add_plot_element(l, Guide.title("Now it has a title"))
```

You can then plot the layer using `plot(l)`, and invoke either `draw` or `display` to actually show something. [Further down](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/Gadfly.jl#L210-L262), there's a bunch of overloads that work on a `Plot` directly:

```
p = plot(x=xs, y=sin(xs))
add_plot_element(p, Guide.title("Now it has a title"))
display(p)
```

I can't find either of these functions in [the documentation](http://dcjones.github.io/Gadfly.jl/index.html), but fortunately the source is comprehensible enough. One of the many joys of Julia =)

Comment: I just got a downvote for this. If there is a problem with this answer, please let me know (or try to [fix it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23625331/edit) :P)