# Plotting list of layers in Gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

I have a list of Gadfly layers with an unknown size:

```
lines = [layer(x=x,y=i*x) for i in range(1,stop=3)]
```

Now I would like to draw all of them in one plot. But Gadfly expects a number of single layers, rather than a list of layers. So
`plot(lines)` doesn't work but `plot(lines[1], lines[2], lines[3])` does.

In Python I'd just use the splat operator `plot(*lines)`.

How can do something like this in Julia?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857793/julia-plotting-unknown-number-of-layers-in-gadfly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to splat it with `...`

```
plot(lines...)
```